# Is there a django package that would allow me to obtain country from a Point field?

Tags: django, geodjango

I am currently using GeoDjango and I have a Point field. Is there a django library out there that would allow me to obtain country from a Point field.Plus point if it gives me a zip code as well. I do not want to pay for external services. Something that is free. Will Django Countries help in this case ?

Comment: I dont see why this needs to be closed ? I would love to know if there is something out there for this

Answer (score 0):

There is not (to the extent of my knowledge) a django module that you can search a country by coordinates.

What you can do is to create a model to store a dataset containing the countries and their corresponding geometries (you can find what you need from this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/495/seeking-administrative-boundaries-for-various-countries) and then query your point against that model.

- `models.py`:

  ```
  class Country(model.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      geom = model.PolygonField() # or what the dataset needs.
      zip_code = model.CharField(max_length=5)
      ...
  ```
- query (assuming that your point is a `Point` object named `my_point`):

  ```
  try:
      country = Country.objects.get(geom__contains=my_point)
  except Country.DoesNotExist:
      print('No country for old men... eerrr given point.')

  print(country.name, country.zip_code, ...)
  ```

---

**PS:** You will find this documentation usefull: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/